# Set x elements in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

In my android project I have a `HashMap<LinearLayout, Boolean> hashmap`. For instance I want to set value for entry 0 till 2 in my `hashmap` to `true`.
Ideally I would want to use `hash.get(0)` etc. but this seems impossible.

Before the downvoting game begins: I'm new to `hashmaps`, and I looked around for methods to solve this.
Any ideas?

Comment: No you will not able to do like that...HashMap only accessible with objects not using position.If you want you can go with some other collections...

Comment: Because I have to add a Boolean. 
Anyway, I guess my best solutions is to make class and throw in the boolean and linearlayout and add an integer for ID.

Comment: That or a custom LinearLayout with that boolean. Does the boolean "belong" to the layout? then you should create a custom Layout.

Comment: linking the boolean to linearlayout as key in a map seems like a **horrible** idea if the view hierarchy gets reconstructed especially if you are using an activity (*orientation change*)

Comment: For now, I made an extra class. I don't have to deal with orientation change.. I'm working on a landscape-only project.
However, it does seem like something I will run into more often, so studying collections is getting higher on my to do list!
Thanks a lot for the input guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap instead of HashMap if you want to maintain the order.